# Item wont add to list box

Tags: c#

Im converting this simple program from vb to c# it updates, displays, create and delete items from a little access database. Bellow is the PopulateListBox() function in VB it goes through every row in the data set and see if it is deleted, not deleted or has errors. I am getting 2 errors here both on the lines 
        lstAlbums.Items.Add(item);
and
        lstAlbums.Items.Add(delitem);
now i realise that the strings are unassigned so i added
string item = "";
string delitem = "";

then when i start the program it fills every second item in th list box with a blank row.

How do i overcome this situation? thank you in advance anyone how can help me.

```
    private void PopulateListBox()
    {
        string item;
        string delitem;
        //clear the list box
        lstAlbums.Items.Clear();

        //access each row in the data set table

        foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables["albums"].Rows)
        {
            //list the nondeleted rows
            if (!((row.RowState & DataRowState.Deleted) == DataRowState.Deleted))
                item = row["albumCode"] + ", " + row["AlbumTitle"] + ", " +                                row["ArtistCode"];
                    //list rows with update errors
                    if (row.HasErrors)
                    item = "(**" + row.RowError + "**)";
                lstAlbums.Items.Add(item);

            //list deleted rows
            if ((row.RowState & DataRowState.Deleted) == DataRowState.Deleted)
                delitem = row["albumCode", DataRowVersion.Original] + ", " 
                    + row["AlbumTitle", DataRowVersion.Original] + ", " 
                    + row["ArtistCode", DataRowVersion.Original] + "***DELETED***";
            lstAlbums.Items.Add(delitem);
         }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the opening and closing braces `{` and `}` in your `if` statement, so the statement immediately following the `if` statement executes if the condition matches, and the statement after that always executes.

In VB.NET your `if` statement resembles this:

```
If condition Then
    ' do something
    ' do something else
End If
```

To translate that to C# and properly execute the 2 lines of code you should use braces:

```
if (condition)
{
    // do something
    // do something else
}
```

Your current translation actually looks like this:

```
if (condition)
    // do something (if condition is true)
// do something else (not dependent on the condition)
```

In other words the 2nd statement always executes. It's a good practice to always enclose multiple statements within the braces to avoid such unintended circumstances.

Change your code to this:

```
if (!((row.RowState & DataRowState.Deleted) == DataRowState.Deleted))
{
    item = row["albumCode"] + ", " + row["AlbumTitle"] + ", " +                                row["ArtistCode"];
    //list rows with update errors
    if (row.HasErrors)
    {
        item = "(**" + row.RowError + "**)";
    }

    lstAlbums.Items.Add(item);
}

//list deleted rows
if ((row.RowState & DataRowState.Deleted) == DataRowState.Deleted)
{
    delitem = row["albumCode", DataRowVersion.Original] + ", " 
        + row["AlbumTitle", DataRowVersion.Original] + ", " 
        + row["ArtistCode", DataRowVersion.Original] + "***DELETED***";
    lstAlbums.Items.Add(delitem);
}
```

Comment: Thank You i did not know that in c# you needed braces around if statements =]

Comment: @Zac: you're welcome. To clarify, you don't need them if you only intend to execute one statement. For multiple statements you do need them. It's cleaner to always use them even if one statement exists so that it's clear exactly what the condition will lead to and it prevents errors like this from sneaking up on you.

Comment: Yes i see. Common mistake i gues going from VB to C# with no notes handed out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is more then on line in **if condition**.  I think thats creats a problem for you. So first include your code between **{}** which depends on **if condition** then Check it.